# JRE not detecting proxy server

Tags: java, maven

We are using the windows 7 64 bit OS and JRE 1.7 and 1.8. The Java and eclipse running behind the proxy server.

We are using Microsoft Forefront TMG client.

We are trying to connect the maven / eclipse market place but its not detecting the TMG server.

Up to java 1.6 there no error while accessing maven / eclipse market place. after upgrade the java we are facing the issue.

Issue: I am unable to connect to Maven Repository(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/....) when I use Java 1.7

where as I am able to connect to maven repository when I use Java 1.6

I used the windows command prompt.

Got below message

```
"[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artif

act descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven

-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:122)

at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:148)

at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.loadPlugin(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:81)

at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:138)

at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:121)

at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:85)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:260)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.jav
```

Comment: Make sure you have added proxy in your settings.xml http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html. If you are using eclipse, goto preferences search for network, it shows all the proxies, select your proxy and run in eclipse.

Comment: I tried giving Proxy information in settings.xml, after adding this information I could see the error is changed from "Connection refused" to "Authentication failure", it looks like proxy information is read from settings.xml, but the credentials I gave in that file is not being send to TMG so TMG is blocking the connection stating Autentication Failure. 
Unable to attach snap shot of the proxy information in settings.xml here.

Comment: I also tried the similar thing in Eclipse, went to Windows-->Preferences-->General-->Network Connections, changed the Active Provider to Manual and set the proxy information, then when I try running Maven pom.xml, I am getting Authentication Failure Error. But I am facing this issue only in Eclipse Luna and higher versions, when I try running Maven pom.xml in Eclipse Kepler(with java 1.6), I am not facing any issues, but at the same time when I use Java 1.7 in Eclipse Kepler, I am again getting Authentication Failure error.

Comment: We are getting the below error:

Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication R
equired ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  ).

Comment: i'm facing the same problem : i'm a consultant in a company and i faced this ^problem with maven and eclipse mars : did you find any solution to this issue ? @smgopinath